# Any suggestions for a highly exothermic reaction in liquid phase but the reactants and products must be pH neutral?

Tags: home-experiment

Need a heat producing reaction for my lab experiment.

Comment: Use an electric kettle.

Comment: Has to be a chemical reaction, no physical heating

Comment: Why chemical reactions and why pH neutral ? What liquid is supposed ? The community likes more extended description of scenario and the own effort of the requester, before helping to provide answers.